# How do I change the size of the text in Skype chat?

Tags: windows, fonts, skype

I find the size of the text in the Skype text chats much too small.  Is there any way I can make it bigger and/or change the font?

I'm using Skype 4.0 on Windows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Tools/Options
- IM & SMS
- IM apperance
- Change

Comment: Don't know how I missed that!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To make the text in Skype the way you want it...

2. Click on Tools
3. Click on Options
4. Click on IM & SMS
5. Click on IM appearance
6. Move the cursor to the box to the right and click on Change font
7. In the Font dialog box that comes up, you can select: Font, Font Style, Size
8. After making the selections, click on ok
9. In the Skype options box, click on Save

Your changes will now be visible.