# Skype font size too small

Tags: windows-7, skype

After installing new updates for Win7, the font sizes of Skype went very small. How can i change it (font of settings, profile names etc)?
Thanks!

Comment: The solution here looks as though it should work for you.

http://superuser.com/a/52724/40682